# MySQL fast search for match in varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to sql, so it's possible I'm doing something stupid.

Anyway, I have a Dictionary table with a VARCHAR(255) word column. I have loaded a dictionary text file into this table. What is the most effective way to check if some VARCHAR(255) is in the dictionary? Currently I am doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE Dictionary
(
word CHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/dictionary.txt'
INTO TABLE Dictionary
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(word);
```

In a procedure, I'm doing

```
DECLARE currentWord VARCHAR(255);
...
IF EXISTS(SELECT word FROM Dictionary WHERE word=currentWord) THEN
...
```

This is taking quite a while. What should I do differently to speed this up?

Comment: add index on word column

Comment: @juergend In what way is using an aggregate simplifying the query?DBMS has to both find the records and then count them.

Comment: @Satya Adding "INDEX(word)" to my Dictionary table declaration speeds things up significantly (the procedure takes less than half the time it did) but it is still pretty slow. Is there anything else I can do? If it matters, the text file I read in is sorted.

Comment: @Kvothe - Are you sure it's the select statement that's making the procedure slow?  Could it be something else that is happening in the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Add a key on the word field as Satya mentioned.  Here's the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE Dictionary ADD KEY `word` (`word`);
```